# How can I copy and move a sequential subset of files?

Tags: shell, scripting, file-copy, seq

I have a directory containing 1772 files named PRC0001, PRC002,... up to PRC1772.

How can I copy a subset, for example PRC0257 to PRC1516 to a different directory? I am trying to do this for several groups of these files, though all groups begin at a given number and continue sequentially to the last item in that group.

I am trying to do this with a bash shell script and parameter.txt file...

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to use zsh's numeric range [glob](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators):

```
mv PRC<257-1516> /else/where/
```

The range operator matches numbers with or without leading zeroes, so `PRC257`, `PRC0257`, `PRC00257`, etc. are all included. You can leave the end of the range blank, e.g. `PRC<257->` to move all files from 257 onwards. It doesn't matter how many files in the range exist. Among the commonplace shells, this feature exists only in zsh.

Bash, ksh93 and zsh support ranges in braces. This is not a glob, but a simple text expansion, e.g. `a{9..11}` expands to `a9 a10 a11` regardless of whether any of these files exist.

```
mv PRC{0257..1516} /else/where
```

You can also combine multiple globs; this has the advantage of working in any shell, but it's unwieldy when your bounds are not round numbers.

```
mv PRC025[7-9] PRC02[6-9][0-9] PRC0[3-9][0-9][0-9] PRC1[0-4][0-9][0-9] PRC150[0-9] PRC151[0-6] /else/where
```

Alternatively, you can be more inclusive in the glob and filter.

```
for x in PRC[0-9]*; do
  n=${x#PRC}
  n=${x%"${x##*[!0]*}"} # strip leading zeroes (beware that numbers with a leading 0 are parsed in octal)
  if [ "$x" -ge 257 ] && [ "$x" -le 1516 ]; then mv "#x" /else/where; fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Select range in braces:

```
cp PRC{0257..1516} destination/
```

Comment: Is this bash specific? If so, you should mention that.